# Authentication Filed on Server. Android Maps API not working

Tags: android, api, authentication, maps, key

I am new to Android Development. I have been creating an app that uses the Android Maps API. It was working well, until I updated my build tools and Android Studio. Now everytime I run it, my map is not shown, and I get the following error:

> 05-11 11:51:54.716    1535-1589/com.pruthvi.lanes I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   05-11 11:52:17.658    1535-1590/com.pruthvi.lanes E/b﹕ Authentication failed on the server.
>   05-11 11:52:17.658    1535-1590/com.pruthvi.lanes E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
>   05-11 11:52:17.668    1535-1590/com.pruthvi.lanes E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>       Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>       Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
>       API Key: AIzaSyA0QeeMrXpO06bvguCeF8iHFHWz3gwHrZw
>       Android Application (;): CC:8B:FA:E7:38:1F:A3:B6:93:A9:D7:EB:1E:2F:56:B9:F1:04:A0:FE;com.pruthvi.lanes

Here's a sample of my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwHrZw" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LeftActivity"
        android:label="Contacts" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RightActivity"
        android:label="Contacts" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TopActivity"
        android:label="Profile"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
```

And heres my Android Maps API file:

```
<resources>
<!--
TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=38:E4:08:5A:74:76:1E:21:32:DB:B2:EF:E9:3E:AD:C0:CF:15:64:73%3Bcom.pruthvi.lanes

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
38:E4:08:5A:74:76:1E:21:32:DB:B2:EF:E9:3E:AD:C0:CF:15:64:73;com.pruthvi.lanes

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
    AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwHrZw
</string>
```

I have tried numerous methods to solve the problem, but nothing is working. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine! Solved! My fingerprint was different in both the console and logcat. Used the one from the logcat and created a key, and now its working smooth. Thanks for the help Darko. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled **Google Maps Android API** (check on this [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled)) and check if your key is valid (this [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials))

Comment: Oh yes. I have enabled the maps API, and I have created a valid key using the developer console. It used to work before, but after updating the build tools and Android studio it has stopped. I have tried multiple keys too, but no improvement.

Comment: Try adding permission and usses-permission

    <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

Comment: Even that's not working. Does it have anything to do with my build files?